# Javascript switching variable from HTML to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables

So far my code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Darek Abe Senior Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Welcome to the Age Calculator!<br>
        <form name="form">
            Birth Year:<br>
            <input type="text" name="birthYear" value="">
            <br>
            Current Year:<br>
            <input type="text" name="currentYear" value=""><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var currentYear = document.getElementById('currentYear');
            alert(currentYear);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I'm trying to figure out, is why it won't alert me of the `currentYear` variable. Please note that I'm very new to this, so there might be some stupid mistakes in there. Also, I'm aware that the `birthYear` variable isn't doing anything, just trying to make sure the one works before moving on.

Comment: I'm still having a problem where the alert just says undefined, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting by Id and you dont have any Id that match, so change the name attribute to Id:

```
<input type="text" id="currentYear" value="">
```

and it will work.

**Note:** Id's must be unique.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5s3ewooz/)

As Larz says, you could get by name like:

```
var currentYear= document.getElementsByName("currentYear")[0];
alert(currentYear.value);
```

But you need to be carefull becouse getElementsByName will return an array becase that needs [0].

Comment: May not need to necessarily _remove_ the name attribute... just _adding_ the id attribute would work too

Comment: @Larz done, I did not explained the getElementsByName because the he refers to getElementsById. thanks :)

Comment: Your answer was fine the way you had it before. I was just referring to where you said "so change the name attribute to Id". You would not need to _change_ the name attribute to make this work. Just _add_ the id, leave the name attribute alone. Then you can still use getElementsById as you said. @Wilfredo P

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` — what's in the name. It selects an element by its id, but the element you are trying to select does not have an id.

Give your elements ids like this:

```
<input type="text" name="currentYear" id="currentYear" />
<!--                                  ^
                                      Give your input field an id -->
```

and then you can use the function:

```
var currentYear = document.getElementById('currentYear');
```

An id must be unique within the document.

---

Alternatively, you can get the element with the function `getElementsByName()`. Of course, in this case, the `<input>` tag doesn't need to have an id.

```
var currentYear = document.getElementsByName('currentYear')[0];
/*                         ^                                ^
         This function returns an array with         We assume that there
         all elements with that name (in this        is only one element
         case 'currentYear').                        with that name, so
                                                     we select index 0 of
                                                     the array.
*/
```

---

**Oh and one more thing:**
*Notice that all HTML elements must either have corresponding closing tags or be self-closing. For instance, `<br>` is invalid, and must be replaced with `<br />`. Same counts for `<input ... />`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form by name by referring to the containing form like this:

```
document.forms['form'].birthYear.value
document.forms['form'].currentYear.value
                ^^^^
            The name of the form
```